# How to prevent executing Linux commands in java in separate process?

Tags: android, process

I am developing application to filter logcat generated by android.I executed linux comand '/system/bin/logcat -b main -f /sdcard/logcat.txt'using getruntme.exec. to execute the command but it is running in separate process though i uninstall my application the process keeps on running .Is there any way i can prevent running in another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By getruntme.exec, do you mean you're using something like this? (borrowed from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419192/java/java/Runtime-getRuntime-exec-String-command)):

```
import java.io.*;
public class TestExec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C dir");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could kill it with p.destroy()

Answer (score 0):

No. `exec` spawns a new process, that is what it is supposed to do - and what you want to do if you start an external command. But it returns a `Process` object that you can use to manipulate the running process.